# C++ Procedure Entry Point Not Found with MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw, libstdc++

I just started a C++ course and am using MinGW to compile (I started doing K&R so already had it set up for C). Whenever I compile a file that includes or uses any library it gives me the following error:

"The procedure entry point ... (this is just a long scrambles-looking thing) could not be located in the dynamic link library ...(the path for the file I'm compiling)"

After googling this I've tried placing libstdc++-6.dll in C:\Windows\System32, placing C:\MinGW\bin as first priority in PATH, and placing libstdc++-6.dll in the same folder as the .cpp file I am compiling.

The only solution was copying it to the folder of the .cpp file I am compiling, but I would like to avoid having to do that every time in the future.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Add `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` to your compiler flags.

Comment: thank you! could you explain what exactly that just did tho?

Comment: These flags make GCC link the standard library (for C and C++ respectively) statically instead of dynamically. I.e. stuff from `.dll`s is now inside of the `.exe` (it probably grew in size by a few megabytes).

Comment: oh, alright! again, thank you! is there anything I can do to avoid having to statically link it every time?

Comment: No, unless you want to copy the `.dll`s to the folder with your `.exe`. I assume you're compiling from a command line, so I'd suggest you to find a proper IDE. Then you won't care how lengthy your list of flags is.

Comment: Oh, alright! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

When building with MinGW, the resulting binaries will need `libstdc++-6.dll` (and some others like `libwinpthread-1.dll`). They contain the standard C++ library, such as `std::string` and friends.

Upon execution your binary will look for these DLLs in specific locations. Usually the error is about a missing DLL, but in your case a wrong version of these DLLs appears to be installed somewhere on your computer without your knowledge. (e.g. 32bit vs 64 bit)

There are two possible solutions:

- Find the **correct DLLs** that shipped with your MinGW toolchain and put them **in the local directory**. (The local directory is the first location where an executable searches for DLLs.) You will have to ship a copy of them along with your build.
- **Link** the standard C++ library **statically** to your program by passing `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` to the linker. This will increase the size of your binaries, and  each binary will contain a redundant copy of the same routines. However, you'll get a self-contained binary.